# Дескриптор {@index элемент} к документирующим комментариям java

Tags: java-9

Объясните, пожалуйста, какую функцию выполняет дескриптор **{@index элемент}** к документирующим комментариям в Java. Этот дескриптор был упомянут в книге, которую я сейчас изучаю, но в дополнительной информации в интернете я не нашел.

Comment: [Раз](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/javadoc/javadoc.htm#JSJAV-GUID-9E6AB571-AB0F-4279-9BBF-C0AF83345BF0), [два](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/225) и [три](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-terms-to-javadoc-search-with-java-9).